Translating pyspark recursive function into sql
I'm experiencing an issue with the following function. I'm trying to translate this to a SQL statement so I can have a better idea of exactly what's happening, so I can more effectively work on my actual issue.
I know that this contains a recursive function between two dataframes and then recursively comparing them until the new dataframe - joined_children has 0 rows. I'm primarily having issue understanding how to write the recursive piece.
def traverse(curr_frame, nodes):
  joined_children = curr_frame.alias('curr')\
    .join(nodes.alias('new'),(col('curr.last_key') == col('new.first_key')) 
    & (col('curr.last_target') == col('new.first_target')))\
.select([col('new.col1'),col('new.col2'), expr('curr.sequence + 1').alias('sequence')])\
    .distinct()
  
  if joined_children.count() == 0:
    return curr_frame
  
  return curr_frame.unionAll(traverse(joined_children, nodes))

df = traverse(root_nodes, condensed_node)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("com_sequence")

Any help is appreciated.
